How to update Excel cell using ADO and VBA
I want to update an Excel cell using ADO and VBA.  The worksheet has numerous columns.  The two columns I am working with are adjacent to each other. I store the SQL statement in variable strADOSQLSting.  In the Immediate window, ? strADOSQLSting resolves to the following string:
UPDATE [Lists$] SET [MiscItemValue] = 'Testing Testing' WHERE [MiscItems] = 'Test'
Note, I am calling the main subroutine from Visio.  Minus the Visio code used to create the Excel Application, Workbook, and Worksheet objects, the code used to update the cell is below.  The code runs without error, but the [MiscItemValue] row is not updated.
' Visio code used to create the Excel Application, Workbook, and Worksheet objects omitted.

Dim strADOSelectCol As String
Dim strSetValue As Variant
Dim strWhereRow As String
Dim strWhereCol As String

' Column to be updated and the value being "SET"
strADOSelectCol = "MiscItemValue"
strSetValue = "Testing Testing"

' Column and value used in "WHERE" clause
strWhereCol = "MiscItems"
strWhereRow = "Test"

'Using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB Provider
strADOConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & strADODataSource & _
                    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    
Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection
adoConn.Open strADOConnection

strADOSQLSting = "UPDATE [" & strADOSheetName & "$]" & _
                 " SET [" & strADOSelectCol & "] = '" & strSetValue & "' WHERE [" & strWhereCol & "] = '" & strWhereRow & "'"
                                                           
adoConn.Execute strADOSQLSting

' Visio code to save and close the Workbook, quit the Application, and release memory omitted.
The derived ADO string, UPDATE [Lists$] SET [MiscItemValue] = 'Testing Testing' WHERE [MiscItems] = 'Test', appears to be correct - so I haven't tried any other methods.
I know how to use Excel VBA to cycle from to bottom of the "MiscItems" column until I find a row with "Test"; and then set the value of "Testing Testing" in the "MiscItemValue" column on the same row.  I thought the more elegant solution would be an ADO UPDATE call.
